# Autowiring class with dynamic param value in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, service, annotations

I want to do the following in my Spring MVC application:

1. Get some data from the database (It will return `List<String> list` ) in my @Service `MainService`.
2. Use this `list` as a constructor parameter for other @Service `ConfigFactory` that I have currently @Autowired in `MainService`.
3. Fire a method from `ConfigFactory` to get final result that will be added to ModelAndView in my @Controller class.

I know it would be possible to this that way:

ConfigFactory class:

```
@Service
public class ConfigFactory(){
    public void init(List<String> list){
        //Use list to initialize ConfigFactory
    }

    public Result getResult(){
        //Do some business logic
        return result;
    }
}
```

MainService class:

```
@Service
public class MainService {
    @Autowired ConfigFactory configFactory;

    public Result method(){
        //Get list from database;
        configFactory.init(list);
        Result result = configFactory.getResult();

        //Create a Result that will be later added to controller ModelAndView. 
    }
}
```

But it doesn't feel nice. So I'm stuck here. Does anyone have an idea how to properly realize this?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you pass the list as a parameter to the getResult() method?
I suppose that you get values from the list in the init() method, and you initialize some properties in your ConfigFactory? Don't do that, you will probably get problems when several users try to do the same thing.

Comment: Yes. I get values based on the logic done in `init()` method which is more than just setting this list. Passing a list there would be a problem if had to later use any other method e.g. `getOtherResult()` because it would require to as well contain this initialization logic. But I think that I will just do that and doesn't create any more public methods there. Thank you for your comment.